# How to im-plement $("<div class='wrapper'><span>Somw text</span></div>") in native javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $("<div class='wrapper'><span>Somw text</span></div>")
```

This piece of code gives me jQuery wrapped object which has the mentioned dom ements. I want to know how can we write the same functionality in native javascript. Is there a DOM API which allows us to pass the well-formed html as string and return the dom node or do we need to parse the string of html and create a document fragment out of it and append the child nodes as we get them.

```
    function getDomFromHtml(htmlStr){
      // some logic ????
      return node;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

[Create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) container `div`, then put string to [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML), then return [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/node.firstChild) of container `div`.

```
function getDomFromHtml (htmlStr){
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    return container.firstChild;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NzHRc/